# BeautifulSoupのインストールについて

Tags: python, macos

Pythonを勉強中の初心者です。
独学プログラマーという本を参考にしながら勉強をしているのですが、スクレイピングをするためにBeautifulSoupをインストールしようとしたところエラーが起きてインストールできませんでした。
pipのバージョンアップしろ的な文章があったのでバージョンアップして再挑戦したのですが、ダメでした。
よろしければ知恵をお貸し下さい。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

メッセージ中にも含まれていますが、`pip install beautifulsoup4` と実行してみてください。

`BeautifulSoup` と指定した場合、古いバージョンを参照しているためエラーになっている可能性があります。

- [beautifulsoup4 4.11.1](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)
- [BeautifulSoup 3.2.2](https://pypi.org/project/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: 入力してみました。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　bash-3.2$ pip3 install beautifulsoup4
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (4.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (2.3.2.post1)これは既にインストールされているということでしょうか？